# Activate TPM Security on BIOS using batch file

Tags: batch-file, powershell-3.0

We are upgrading OS Windows 7 to Windows 10 on computers.
For upgrading to Windows 10 we need to activate TPM Security on BIOS on Win 10. Currently I am trying to find if there is any way of changing the BIOS setting from Windows 7 using automated script? when client is restarted after adding the script on the computer.

Thanks in advance :)
Sandeep